# Access denied when trying to connect to MariaDB using PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, wamp

I have WAMPServer 3.2.6 on Windows 10 (64bit), and I'm able to connect to MariaDB using phpMyAdmin without any problem.

Now I want to connect the database with same user account by running php script instead.

Here is relevant part of my script file, test.php:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "xdurxttx_gromates";
$username ="root"; //"xdurxttx_gromates";
$password =""; //"gromatespassword";

 // Create connection. Following line causes the "access denied" error
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

I also tried a regular db user account, xdurxttx_gromates, and the result was the same.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could give me some hint, guiding me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

toby

Exact Error Message: :)

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in D:\Data\b4a\apps\gromates\deedeegroup.com\root\public_html\gromate\php\testgromate.php on line 23 
> Call Stack # Time Memory Function Location 1 0.0015 362400 {main}( ) ...\testgromate.php:0 2 0.0015 362784 __construct( $host = 'localhost', $user = 'root', $password = '', $database = 'xdurxttx_gromates' ) ...\testgromate.php:23 Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: WAMPServer comes with both MySQL and mariaDB installed and started. By default mariaDB uses port 3307 and MySQL 3306. Read `C:\wamp64\mariadb_mysql.txt` to see the various options you have, from swapping ports for MySQL and mariaDB to removing MySQL or simply making mariaDB the default (uses port 3306)

Comment: @Barmar, here is the error message ```Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
(using password: NO) in
D:\Data\b4a\apps\gromates\deedeegroup.com\root\public_html\gromate\php\testgromate.php
on line 23
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0015 362400 {main}( ) ...\testgromate.php:0
2 0.0015 362784 __construct( $host = 'localhost', $user = 'root', $password =
'', $database = 'xdurxttx_gromates' ) ...\testgromate.php:23
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)```

Comment: Are you sure the root password is ""? Have you tried "root" for both the username and the password?

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click WAMP icon->select WAMP Settings->Uncheck Mysql and check MariaDB if unchecked, as shown in the attached image.   After that it works like a charm for me.
[image: Allow one database, Mysql or MariaDB]